# Subroutes in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I have a main component with routes:

```
@Routes([
            {
                path     : "/auth/login",
                component: AuthComponent
            },
            {
                path     : "/",
                component: DefaultComponent
            }
        ])
```

DefaultComponent routes:

```
@Routes([
            {
                path     : "/",
                component: LevelListComponent
            },
            {
                path     : "/levels/:id/add",
                component: LevelListComponent
            },
            {
                path     : "/levels/:id/edit",
                component: LevelListComponent
            },
            {
                path     : "/scripts",
                component: ScriptListComponent
            }
        ])
```

When I try to navigate to /scripts I see an error:

```
app.js:44947 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot match any routes. Current segment: 'undefined'. Available routes: ['/auth/login', '/']
```

In beta I could do:

```
{
   path: "/...",
   component: SomeComponent
}
```

But now it's not working.

And how can I do create a dynamic route in template?

```
<a [routerLink]="menuItem.url">
```

Comment: That's not enough information to debug the problem.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer that's better?

Comment: Have you tried to replace the `'/'` with `'*'` like so `path     : "*",`?

Comment: @rinukkusu yes, but nothing work then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reorder the routes in `DefaultComponent` so that the more specific ones come first and the less specific ones come last (`/` to be the last one). This is a know issue and will probably be fixed with the next release.

Comment: Maybe you know when probable be next release?

Comment: No idea. . . . . .

Comment: I tried to remove "/" route in DefaultComponent but sill have an error